# Noah and his ark - inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

By spending an emerald, Noah turns a swan into a frog or a duck into a lizard, and by spending a ruby, he turns a swan into a duck or a frog into a lizard. Today he spent 20 emeralds and 23 rubies, and the number of frogs increased by 5. How and how much can the number of ducks change? (Give all possible results and explain why).

I found this in a Facebook group.

Let's name $S_0, F_0, D_0, L_0$ the initial number of each kind and $S_e, F_e, D_e, L_e$ their numbers after the exchange with the use of emeralds.
Clearly we have, for 1 emerald, $S_0-S_n = F_n-F_0$, therefore for $x$ emeralds, $x(S_0-S_n) = x(F_n-F_0)$.

Also for $y$ emeralds,
$y(D_0-D_n) = y(L_n-L_0)$.

We have $x+y=20$.

We get similar equations for the rubies:
$z(S_0-S_m) = z(D_m-D_0)$.

$w(F_0-F_m) = w(L_m-L_0)$.

$z+w=23$.

The difference in number of frogs after all transformations is 5 but I don't know how to take into account the consecutive transformations; it is getting very complicated.

Comment: I think there is no need to use a multiplication symbol at all in your post. But if you want to use one I think that $\cdot$ (`\cdot`) is more appropriate than the asterisk $*$ (`*`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We define $r_1$ as the number of rubies used to transform swans to ducks and $r_2,e_1,e_2$ in a similar way according to the following diagram.

```
      e2
   D ----> L
   ^       ^
   |       |
r1 |       |r2
   |       |
   S ----> F
      e1
```

then the following holds, where $\Delta X$ is the change in the expression $X$ after all transformations are applied.

$$\begin{eqnarray}
e=e_1+e_2\\
r=r_1+r_2
\end{eqnarray}$$

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\Delta(D+L)=e\\
\Delta(F+L)=r
\end{eqnarray}$$

$$\begin{eqnarray} 
   \Delta(D+L)=\Delta D + \Delta L\\
   \Delta(F+L)=\Delta F + \Delta L
\end{eqnarray}$$

$$\begin{eqnarray}
e=20\\
r=23
\end{eqnarray}$$

Additionally we know that
$$ \Delta F= 5$$

From the above we get
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\Delta F + \Delta L&=&20\\
\Delta D + \Delta L&=&23\\
\Delta F&=&5
\end{eqnarray}$$
and therefore
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\Delta L&=& 15\\
\Delta D&=& 8 \\
\Delta F&=&5 
\end{eqnarray}$$
So the number of Ducks changes by $8$.

We also see that the number of lizard increased by $15$ The number of animals did not change. So the number of swans decreases by $\Delta L+\Delta D+\Delta F=28$.

Comment: I was originally going to post this solution (from $f$ frogs to $f+x+y-23$) but I think there's a catch when the starting number of swans is less than $28$.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire if Noah increased the number of frogs by 5 by spending 20 emeralds and 23 rubies than the number of swans was 28 or more. Otherwise it would be impossible to achieve what is claimed in the question. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

This story is a reported fact. Therefore we may assume that there are enough animals of all sorts around to make it possible.

I denote the number of animals $\>a$...$\ $ turned to $\>b$...$\ $ by $\vec{ab}$. According to the story we have
$$\vec{sf}+\vec{dl}=20,\quad \vec{sd}+\vec{fl}=23,\quad\vec{sf}-\vec{fl}=\Delta f=5$$
and therefore
$$\Delta d=\vec{sd}-\vec{dl}=(23-\vec{fl})-(20-\vec{sf})=3+(\vec{sf}-\vec{fl})=8\ .$$

Comment: Both solutions are correct and very nice; I accepted the one by miracle123 only because it was the first one. Thank you very much both.